# How to make author field required?

Tags: 8, forms

In Drupal 8. I noticed that I can create a new node or edit a current node and delete the "Authored By" name, it's blank and when I hit save the node is authored by Anonymous.

How can I make this Author field required to be a current user in the system?

And the page will show a message and will not save until a name is entered. I tried this but it does not work:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function demo4_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

I also tried this:

```
function demo4_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ( $form_id == 'page_node_form'){
$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
return $form;
}
```

This works only in Drupal 7 not in Drupal 8, And I changed `page_node_form` to `node_page_form` for Drupal 8

```
function demo4_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {

$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
 }
   return $form;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return the `$form` in a form alter, it is passed by reference. Second, you have to type hint `$form_state` with `FormStateInterface`. You need the `use` statement as well.

Comment: So do it like this? use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
function demo4__form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}

Comment: By using the `use` statement you don't have to specify the fully qualified name - only the name itself, so just `FormStateInterface $form_state` is needed. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: I tried this but its still not required- use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
function demo4__form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}

Comment: Yes I was mainly saying the syntax of your code needed correction. Are you certain that's the form field key? Have you debugged your code to see it add #required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

`$form['uid']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;`

(Devel is your friend!)

You were on the right track as `$form['author']['#required'] = TRUE;` will make the "Authoring Information" have a red star (*), but won't make your authored by field required.

Complete code:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
    $form['uid']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I enabled Devel and Devel Kint. Then in devel settings I checked Kint and display page array. Then placed this inside hook form alter- dpm($form); And then I went to create a basic page and I see the Input array of 41 items but I dont see the elements for the admin settings box, like author by, revision...? Where can I find information on how to use devel and kint to find elements?

Comment: Incase anyone needs this code here it is, it may be hard to read. 
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
function demo4_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, 
$form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'node_page_form') {
$form['uid']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#required'] = TRUE;
 }
   return $form;
}

Comment: THanks again CliveCleaves. With dpm I did find all the elements inside the admin box like - uid, author, revision, and inside those I found the widget and title